# How to move this nav bar vertically and horizontally in the center of the side bar

Tags: html, css

Image is a bit long, please scroll down to see the code.

[image]

I'm trying to make this nav-bar vertically aligned while it looks too ugly.
How can I move Logo to the top of the Nav links and nav links move to the center of the nav vertically and horizontally. Nav bar must be full height and fixed.
Here is the code:

```
.site-header  {
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 18rem;
    height: 100vh;
        margin:auto !important
}

.logo {
     display: flex;
      margin: auto auto 0;
      padding: 0.5rem;
}

.primary-menu {
flex-direction: column;
 width: 100%;

}

.primary-menu > li {
    display: block; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check out this code snippet. i could not see your logo, that's why i did not include it. but you can do it using the format there

```css
.header {
   display: flex;
}

.header nav {
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.header nav ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

.header nav ul > li {
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
}

.header nav ul > li > a {
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
   color: #333;
   padding: 7px 12px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-family: Montserrat;
}

.header nav ul > li > a > img {
   display: inline-block;
   max-width: 100px
   max-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class='header'>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='/'><img src='' alt='logo' /></a></li>
            <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='featurs'>Features</a></li>
            <li><a href='developers'>Developers</a></li>
            <li><a href='testimonials'>Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href='auth/signup' class='reg-btn'>Signup</a></li>
        <ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: The logo is in the left top side. It looks to small I don't know why :(

Comment: i have included a location for your logo. simply put the url for the logo image. adjust the styling as you want too

Comment: did that meet your need?

Comment: but it works on the code snippet here. you did not copy the html and css i wrote?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below css:

```
.site-header  {
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:auto !important;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.logo {
     display: block;
     margin: auto auto 0;
     padding: 0.5rem;
}
.primary-menu {
    flex-direction: inherit;
    width: 100%;
}
.primary-menu > li {
    display: block; 
}
```